# Nuxt - Axios requests on server side not sending referer

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

#### The story

My backend app provides SEO information for my sites pages. One of this informations are OpenGraph meta tags, such as `og:type` and `og:url`.
`og:url` value is given by the API through the HTTP "Referer" header.

#### What I'm doing now

I'm using Axios module to make my requests.
Through `asyncData` function in my pages I can get the `req` variable and it's `headers.referer` property, which is what I want, like this:

```
// page.vue
async asyncData({ app, req }) {
  app.$axios.setHeader('Referer', req.headers.referer);
}
```

#### The problem

If I am at the index page, let's say, then I click in a link to a dynamic page I got an error, for `req` is not available on `asyncData` function while navigating, *I suppose*.

#### The question

How can I dynamically get my requests referers to send it with Axios request for both client-side and server-side requests?

Info about the versions:

- nuxt: 1.4.2
- @nuxtjs/axios: 5.3.1

Comment: Maybe you can use [axiso interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) for this. Look at the example `axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {...`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
async asyncData({ app, req }) {
  const referrer = process.client ? window.document.referrer :  req.headers.referer
  app.$axios.setHeader('Referer', referrer)
}
```